# Moving a node to the end of a chain of nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, nodes

I have a function where I have to move an existing code for example

```
def print_chain_and_ids(chain):
    current = chain
    while current != None:
        print(id(current), current.get_data())
        current = current.get_next()

a = Node('first')
b = Node('middle')
c = Node('last')
a.set_next(b)
b.set_next(c)

print_chain_and_ids(a)
move_node_to_end(a, 'middle')    

print_chain_and_ids(a)
```

so now the chain goes:

`a ----> b ----> c`

with the node `c` at the end of the chain.

If I wanted to move the node `b` to the end of the chain so it goes:

`a ----> c ----> b`

so that it doesn't change the value of the last node but just moves it around. I have a node class ready:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)
```

I wanted to know how I would go about doing this.

I want to make to make a function which takes two inputs, the first node of the chain, and also the value which moves to the last position of the chain. So:

```
def node_to_end(first_node, value_to_move):
    .....
```

This is where I have to modify the position of the nodes. So that value to move goes to the last position.

```
a = Node('blue')
b = Node('red')
c = Node('green')

a.set_next(b)
b.set_next(c)
```

which would result in `blue red green`

```
node_to_end(a, 'red')
```

would create a chain of

`blue green red`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: So you want `c` to point at `b` and `a` to point at `c` and `b` to point at nothing? You already wrote a `set_next` method just use it to make them point to what you want it to be.... I don't understand your question. sorry.

Comment: I want b to point at c and c to point at b. I don't want the values of b and c to change just the position.

Comment: Currently `b=a.next` and `c=a.next.next`. Now do: `a.next = c`; `c.next=b`; `b.next=None`

Comment: I think you need to re-read your linked-list notes, not to be rude or anything. IF `b->c` and `c->b` then it's not what you gave as an example: `a ----> c ----> b`. You still have the tools to 'move' the nodes around. I still fail to understand what you don't understand about the program you wrote. If you didn't write the program, maybe you should ask your teacher/tutor/author on how to use the program. From what you showed us, you should already know what to do.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can do that with just a 'next' link. You might have to add a 'prev' link to your Node class. You can use b.prev to find node a, b.next to find node c, and then change the links on all three nodes.

Comment: I'm sorry I might have been a bit unclear. I meant to say that the existing chain should not be changed. So I don't want to modify the chain. I want to write a new function which changes it using the node class that I have made.

Comment: Wha? You're not being clear. First you write "the existing chain should not be changed" then later that "I want to write a new function which changes it". Plus, in the question itself, you state "I have to modify the position of the nodes", which again sounds like the original chain is being changed. Please [edit] your question and clarify exactly what the result is of calling this new function (including what effect it has, if any, on the original chain of nodes). If it can't change the original it will have to copy most of it before making any modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chain-of-nodes is very similar to what is called a singly-linked-list. With those, nodes are typically removed by keeping track of the *previous* node while traversing along the list, that way when the target node is found, you'll know which one (if any) came before it. Having that piece of information allows the list to be easily modified.

Here's how to apply that to your code. I also added a little utility to print the contents of chains to make it clear what is in them.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

def move_to_end(start, target):
    """Move target node from the chain beginning with start to end."""
    previous = None
    current = start
    while current:
        if current.get_next() is target:
            previous = current
            break
        current = current.get_next()

    if previous:  # target found in chain?
        previous.set_next(target.get_next())  # remove it
        # and move it to the end
        current = target
        while current:
            if not current.get_next():  # last node in chain?
                target.set_next(None)
                current.set_next(target)
                break
            current = current.get_next()

def print_node_chain(start):
    """Utility to print out a node chain starting from given node."""
    values = []
    current = start
    while current:
        values.append(str(current))
        current = current.get_next()

    print(' ----> '.join(values) + ' ----> None')

a = Node('blue')
b = Node('red')
c = Node('green')

a.set_next(b)
b.set_next(c)

print_node_chain(a)
move_to_end(a, b)
print_node_chain(a)
```

Output:

```
blue ----> red ----> green ----> None
blue ----> green ----> red ----> None
```

Comment: How do I get rid of the `None` so that it just prints out `blue ----> red ----> green` and `blue ----> green ----> red`. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Seriously? Just remove it from the code that's displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

Well this will require some computation. Let's assume the generic case:

*e<sub>i-1</sub> -> e<sub>i</sub> -> e<sub>i+1</sub> -> ...  -> e<sub>n</sub>*

Now we want to move  *e<sub>i</sub>* to the last position:

*e<sub>i-1</sub> -> e<sub>i+1</sub> -> ...  -> e<sub>n</sub> -> e<sub>i</sub>*

So the question is: what should change? Based on the generic case, there are three pointers that must change:

- *e<sub>i-1</sub>* now points to  *e<sub>i+1</sub>*;
- *e<sub>i</sub>* now points to nothing (`None`); and
- *e<sub>n</sub>* now points to *e<sub>i</sub>*.

Now since the linked list is **not doubly linked**: a node has no reference to the previous node, the only thing we can do to get the previous element, is **iterate from the root** until we find the element:

```
def get_prev_element(root,node):
    while root.get_next() is not node:
        root = root.get_next()
```

Once we have the previous element, we can let it link to the next element:

```
previous.set_next(node.get_next())
```

But now we still have to find out what the last element is. And guess what, we do this again, by **iterating**, we can however start from our own node:

```
def get_last(node):
    while node.get_next() is not None:
        node = node.get_next()
    return node
```

Now we set the `next` of the last node, to our own node:

```
last.set_next(node)
```

and finally we set our own next to `None`:

```
node.set_next(None)
```

Now grouping this all together we can define a method **on the node**:

```
class Node:

    # ...

    def get_previous(self,root):
        previous = root
        while previous.get_next() is not self:
            previous = previous.get_next()
        return previous

    def get_last(self):
        last = self
        while last.get_next() is not None:
            last = last.get_next()
        return last

    def move_last(self,root):
        previous = self.get_previous(root)
        previous.set_next(self.get_next())
        last = self.get_last()
        last.set_next(self)
        self.set_next(None)
```

Note that since the linked list is not double linked, you will have to give it the root element.

---

**Intermezzo**: given you have references to `a`, `b` and `c`. Of course there is no reason to calculate the previous and last: you know that `a` is the previous and that `c` is the last. So in that case, the code is simply:

```
a.set_next(c)
c.set_next(b)
b.set_next(None)
```

---

This code **does not work** if the root element is the node itself. I leave it as an exercise to modify the code to let it work properly. It is not very hard.